# Error "intent", android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth

Estoy haciendo una conexión con bluetooth, de donde lo saque de YouTube, pero llevo ya varias horas intentando encontrar el error de esto pero no puedo solucionarlo.
Me marca errores en varias partes del código, que incluso ya investigue en varios foros y no eh logrado encontrar nada y en los intent, Les proporciono imagenes para que puedan visualizar los errores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar, en donde me esta marcando los errores, es casi el mismo mensaje que me esta enviando y no logro decifrar que pasa, ojala me puedan ayudar

Les proporciono el código para que puedan visualizarlo mejor:

```
package com.example.bluetooth_2;


import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 0;
private static final int REQUEST_DISCOVER_BT = 1;

private TextView mStatusBleTv, mPairedTv;
ImageView mBlueIV;
Button mOnBtn, mOffBtn, mDiscoverBtn, mPairedBtn;
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mStatusBleTv = findViewById(R.id.statusBluetooth);
    mPairedTv = findViewById(R.id.pirTv);
    mBlueIV = findViewById(R.id.bluetooth;
    mOnBtn = findViewById(R.id.onButn);
    mOffBtn = findViewById(R.id.offButn);
    mDiscoverBtn = findViewById(R.id.discoverableBtn);
    mPairedBtn = findViewById(R.id.PairedBtn);

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
        mStatusBleTv.setText("Bluetooth is not available");
    } else {
        mStatusBleTv.setText("Bluetooth is  available");


        if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            mBlueIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluetooth);
        } else {
            mBlueIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluetoothimage2);

        }

        mOnBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    showToast("Turning on Bluetooth..");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                } else {
                    showToast("Bluetooth is already on");

                }
            }
        });

        mDiscoverBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                    showToast("Making Your Device Discoverable");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DISCOVER_BT);
                }
            }
        });
        mOffBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    bluetoothAdapter.disable();
                    showToast("Turning  Bluetooth off");
                    mBlueIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluetoothimage2);
                } else {
                    showToast("Bluetooth is already off");

                }
            }
        });

        mPairedBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    mPairedTv.setText("Paired Devices");
                    Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

                    for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
                        mPairedTv.append("\n Device : " + device.getName() + " , " + device);
                    }
                } else {
                    showToast("Turn On bluetooth to get paired devices");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mBlueIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluetooth);
                showToast("Bluetooth is On");
            } else {
                showToast("Bluetooth is Off");

            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

private void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Cabe recalcar que los permisos ya los agregue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Bluetooth_2"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Quizá sea algo muy sencillo pero apenas estoy empezando con Android Studio, de verdad espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: Hola ya probaste dando click derecho sobre la línea de error y aplicar las sugerencias que te menciona?

Comment: Ya, pero me marca mas errores

Comment: Creo que esos errores son simplemente porque Android Studio espera que se verifique la disponibilidad de permisos con [`checkSelfPermission`](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#already-granted). Si das clic en el link de **Add permission check** se arreglará. Es bastante molesto pero me parece que se puede desactivar con anotaciones.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es relacionado a permisos, revisa los mensajes que obtienes.

> Para las aplicaciones dirigidas a Build.VERSION_CODE#R (Android 12) o
> anterior, esto requiere el permiso **Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH** que
> se puede obtener con una simple etiqueta de manifiesto
> .

**Debes agregar el permiso simplemente en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`**

> Para las aplicaciones dirigidas a Build.VERSION_CODE#S (android 13) o
> superior, esto requiere el permiso **Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN**
> que se puede obtener con Activity,requestPermissions(String[], int)

**Debes agregar el permiso en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` y requerir la petición de permisos manualmente.** [En el sitio puedes encontrar información sobre petición de permisos en Android.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=android%20permisos)